# API POST Response for Hierarchical objects

Tags: rest

If I am sending a POST request to update some object in a DB, such as :

```
User{
    id: 20,
    name: "Jack",
    UserAssociations:[{
                   id: 100,
                   association: object1
               },{....}]
   ........
}
```

Where I am sending a parent object along with an array of child objects to a REST service, but I am expecting the IDs that I get from the server to be different than what I have.  So my local ID for user Jack might be 20, but in the database itself, it will be 50.  Same for the child objects.  What is the best practice in returning a response message that maps the old ID value with the new ID value.  I want to push this all as one transaction (where if any part of the POST fails, the entire thing fails).  The only way I can think of right now is something like:

```
      Response{
         success: "status message",
         id: 50,
               UserAssociations: [{
                    originalID: 100,
                    newID: 8421
                     }]
        }
```

Where I just have an array of values for each child object containing 2 fields, the ID I passed into it and the new ID I'm retrieving.  The main issue I'm having with this is that it would require me to loop through my data locally to match up the IDs to update.  Is there a better practice that I'm missing to avoid this?

Comment: If id 20 doesn't actually map to Jack in the database, then what *does* it map to?  If you already have the new id, then why are you passing the old one at all? To put it another way, why do the id's differ?

Comment: use GUIDs and you wont have this (and other) problems

Comment: The IDs differ because one is created locally and offline while the other is generated at the server.  I can't guarantee that an ID on the local side won't conflict with an ID created on the server's side.  Also, @Ewan, I don't have the ability to change the ID types used in the DB.  They're just auto-incrementing integer values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the common approach where the Id's change or are created on inserting into the database is to return the whole new object.

You then discard whatever object you sent and replace it with the new one from the server.

You don't care which of your old child objects maps to the new ones, because you have simply discarded them.

The other approach of course is to generate your Ids client side and not on the database. You can then keep the same ids.

Comment: I guess the only thing I don't like about this is the additional bandwidth used/data processed.  It seems wasteful and a bit costlier (though probably somewhat negligible) to pass that much duplicated data when all that's needed is one pair of data points for each object.  But that at least makes the client side easier to deal with as a tradeoff.

Comment: The benefit I feel is in having an approach which works regardless of what changed. often you will have some other fields, status, created date etc. which change or are populated when you save

Comment: Ive seen 'delta' approaches for large datasets, but these soon become very complicated